# Entity Framework and Same Table Foreign Keys

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

To describe what I want: assume I have a table `User` in SQL Server, which contains the primary key field, and two fields that refer back to the same table using foreign keys.

```
CREATE TABLE [User] (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    -- other properties omitted for brevity
    CreatedByUserID INT NOT NULL,
    LastModifiedByUserID INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_User PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_User_CreatedByUser FOREIGN KEY (CreatedByUserID) REFERENCES User 
(ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_User_LastModifiedByUser FOREIGN KEY (LastModifiedByUserID) REFERENCES User (ID),
)
```

I can setup the "root" user by executing the following SQL:

```
INSERT [User] (CreatedByUserID, LastModifiedByUserID) VALUES (1, 1)
```

SQL Server doesn't throw any errors.

Now, if I try to create the same table using Entity Framework Code First, I get mixed results:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(CreatedByUser))]
    public int CreatedByUserID { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey(nameof(ModifiedByUser))]
    //public int ModifiedByUserID { get; set; }

    public virtual User CreatedByUser { get; set; }

    //public virtual User ModifiedByUser { get; set; }
}
```

This works as shown, but when I uncomment the ModifiedByUser* lines then I get a variety of "Multiplicity is not valid in Role" errors.

I've tried converting my annotation-driven class to a fluent-style configuration, but I have no luck when I run `Add-Migration`: there's always some error that crops up for some combination of configuration methods, and I never seem able to specify the `CreatedByUserID` or `LastModifiedByUserID` column names.

```
user.HasRequired(x => x.CreatedBy);
    //.WithRequiredPrincipal();
user.HasRequired(x => x.LastModifiedBy);
    //.WithRequiredPrincipal();
```

Am I trying to do something that's forbidden by Entity Framework? Or have I missed a line or two of configuration? How can I use EF to recreate the table structure shown at the top of this post?

**EDIT:**
The same pattern works just fine for a number of other entities in the model: for example a `WorkItem` can have both `CreatedByUser` and `ModifiedByUser`; the problem only seems to arise when the foreign keys refer back to an entity of the same type as their enclosing type.

Comment: This is impossible in EF6 (not sure about EF Core) because it ignores explicit PK values for autogenerated keys. You'd better change the design by allowing null `CreatedByUserId` - a "standard" approach for resolving such issues.

Comment: I am using EF 6. Allowing just one (or even both) of the two foreign keys to be nullable doesn't solve the problem for me. I tried with annotations as well as fluent API. I get the same error that "Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'."

Comment: You've got me wrong. The model *can* be configured fluently - `user.HasRequired(x => x.CreatedBy).WithMany();` + `user.HasRequired(x => x.LastModifiedBy).WithMany();`. But you won't be able to create `User` with `CreatedByUserId` equals to the same `User` Id as in the SQL example (except if you use SQL directly and have `identity_insert` enabled).